# android in-app billing error ( real productId )

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I have a ERROR with testing a real product. When I click a buy button, have Error  "This version of the application is not configured for Market billing".

I use this example https://github.com/robotmedia/AndroidBillingLibrary.

I input my publish key and productId. Put permissions in Manifest. How I can fix this?

Answer (score 1):

you have to sign your apk with your private key and upload (but not necessarily published) to the market in order for your real product to work